# How can I create singletons of derived classes?

Tags: java, singleton

I was asked this question in an interview . I have a base class (say class `A`) and then two subclasses `B` and `C`. Now I have no control over the constructor of B and C(those constructors can't be private , has to be public ) but the requirement is that every instance of `B` and `C`should be a **singleton** . How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What does it mean no control? You cant change its code (you don't need to)? or you cant change its visibility?

Comment: can you define `no control over the constructor`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I'd do this in the constructor for `A`.  Get it to call `this.getClass()`, and use that to do a lookup in private HashSet.  If you get a hit, then an instance of the class has previously been created, and you throw an exception.

```
public abstract class A {
    private static HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public A () {
        synchronized (classes) {
            Class<?> c = this.getClass();
            if (classes.contains(c)) {
                throw NotSingletonException("Class " + c + " is not singleton");
            }
            classes.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

If you arrange that all of A's constructors do this, then subclasses cannot avoid the check.  And since the JLS won't let you put a try / catch around a `this()` or `super()` call, the constructor for the subclass can't ever return  normally once that exception has been thrown.

---

I'd say that this is a pretty hard interview question ...

---

@emory comments:

> What if B and C are not final? Then I could create classes B1, B2, C1, C2, etc.

The problem here (if it counts as a problem) is that the B1 and B2 instances are also B instances, and that means that the B instance is no longer a singleton ... depending on the definition of singleton you are aspiring to implement.

I can see a couple of ways of dealing with this:

- You could reflectively test the subclass modifiers see if the classes are final, and refuse to create instances of non-final classes ... just in case.
- You could replace the `HashSet<Class>` with a `List<Class>`.  Then each time the `A` constructor is called, it would iterate over the list calling `elem.isAssignableFrom(c)` for each element class.  If any call returns true, the (strict) singleton invariant is violated so an exception should be thrown.

The logic may need to be adjusted depending on the model of singleton-ness you are trying to enforce, but the general solution applies: record the classes and examine / compare new classes with previous ones.

Comment: What if B and C are not final? Then I could create classes B1, B2, C1, C2, etc.  I suppose you could solve that problem (if it counts as a problem) by adding successively getting `c`'s superclass until just before `c` is A.

Answer (score 0):

I am showing it for the class B

Though you can use `Double checked locking`, and `synchronized on method` to do it.. i am showing you a quick and dirty way of doing it...

```
public class B {

    private static B b = new B();

    private B() {}

    public static B getInstance() {
           return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: see the edited question . constructor of B can not be private .